# Manga with main character accidentally killing someone else in a monster trap; references to carrots

Tags: story-identification, manga

Main character accidently kills someone/hero/knight? using a trap meant for killing monsters, a page had the main character and other people with white carrots? Or is it.. they loved the "carrots" because it's like thighs.

Comment: You may get downvotes as your question currently stands. If you add in more details of the manga people might be able to hep you more, not just details about the manga itself, but other stuff as well. When did you first read it, what language, was it colored or black and white, a series or one off, etc. Anything else that you can possibly think of that might help narrow down options. Welcome to the SciFi stack!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like [Yuusha ga Shinda! Murabito no Ore ga Hotta Otoshiana ni Yuusha ga Ochita Kekka](https://myanimelist.net/manga/85941/Yuusha_ga_Shinda__Murabito_no_Ore_ga_Hotta_Otoshiana_ni_Yuusha_ga_Ochita_Kekka). The main character, Touka Scott, is a raddish farmer obsessed with thighs. In the first chapter he likens a particular radish to an attractive thigh. He also crafts anti-demon traps in his fields.

Comment: Thank you for finding the manga, I had the manga saved, but it somehow unsaved. Thank you.